# PascalCase to camelCase, Finding and replacing in an angular proj

Tags: angular, typescript, camelcasing, pascalcasing

So, I was just wondering if there is a software or a program that identifies PascalCase and then covert it to camelCase? Or at least just identify/find the PascalCase so that I could do it myself manually. I am currently picking the cases manually and changing them from each file which feels like labor work honestly, so repetitive and boring. It would really help me out if someone knows such thing, thanks.

[Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfY1w.png)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [lodash](http://lodash.com) library. It cannot determine whether string is in PascalCase or not, but it can convert anything to camelCase.
Take a look onto this function [`_.camelCase`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#camelCase)

```js
_.camelCase('PascalCase') // => 'pascalCase'
```